Angular's typed union type FormGroup
I have an application in which user is choosing the value from dropdown and based on choosed value,  type of FormGroup will be used. This formGroup is used as "additional informations"
I use exactly three types, or don't use the formGroup at all. I want to improve the codebase and add the typing as the old code came from the times before the typed reactive forms was a thing in Angular.
The FormGroup types does not have any common fields.
Here is simplified demo
I have tried to use FormGroup<TeacherForm | PolicemanForm | FireFighterForm>, but it did not work.
What is the best way to handle this kind of formGroups?
Thank you.

We can create a union type | and make all the params optional using ?: then we can freely use them, I also merged the types into a single union type UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES
I kept the types separate, since when you are certain that a type will be teacher, you can cast it using <TeacherForm> or as TeacherForm
export class FireFighterForm {
  interventions?: FormControl<number | null> = new FormControl<number | null>(
    null
  );
}

export class PolicemanForm {
  department?: FormControl<number | null> = new FormControl<number | null>(
    null
  );
}

export class TeacherForm {
  specialization?: FormControl<number | null> = new FormControl<number | null>(
    null
  );
}

export type UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES =
  | TeacherForm
  | PolicemanForm
  | FireFighterForm
  | null;

FULL CODE:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropdownChangeEvent } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { FireFighterForm } from './forms/firefighter.form';
import { PolicemanForm } from './forms/policeman.form';
import { TeacherForm } from './forms/teacher.form';

export type UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES =
  | TeacherForm
  | PolicemanForm
  | FireFighterForm
  | null;

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-reactive-forms-demo',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-reactive-forms-demo.html',
  styles: `.card,form { display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 10px;}`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
})
export class DropdownReactiveFormsDemo {
  personTypes: string[] = [
    'Teacher',
    'Policeman',
    'Firefighter',
    'Bank',
    'Shop',
    'Insurance Company',
  ];
  selectedPersonType: string | undefined;

  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    surname: new FormControl(''),
    additionalInfo: new FormGroup<UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES>({}), // HOW TO TYPE PROPERLY?
    // additionalInfo: new FormGroup<TeacherForm | PolicemanForm | FireFighterForm | null>(null) // does not work
  });

  onPersonTypeChange(event: DropdownChangeEvent) {
    if (event.value === 'Teacher') {
      this.formGroup.setControl(
        'additionalInfo',
        new FormGroup<UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES>(new TeacherForm())
      );
    } else if (event.value === 'Policeman') {
      this.formGroup.setControl(
        'additionalInfo',
        new FormGroup<UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES>(new PolicemanForm())
      );
    } else if (event.value === 'Firefighter') {
      this.formGroup.setControl(
        'additionalInfo',
        new FormGroup<UNION_FORM_GROUP_TYPES>(new FireFighterForm())
      );
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

This looks great, thank you! However, the IDE does not suggest any controls - this.formGroup.controls.additionalInfo.controls. shows nothing.

@Marek to my knowledge typescript cannot handle that level of dynamically typing the forms type, since it's a statically typed language, I would suggest you make the form private so that dirct access is prohibited, then you can write getter that will type cast the form to contain all the form controls so that intellisense recognises it

You can use FormRecord to create forms with dynamically added and removed control
Here's how it works:
  formGroup = new FormRecord({
     name: new FormControl(''),
     ...
   });   

   if (event.value === 'Teacher') {
      this.formGroup.setControl(
        'additionalInfo',
        new FormGroup(new TeacherForm()) -->FormGroup
      );
   }  

In your template, use the formGroupName directive to group related controls within the dynamic form group:
<ng-container formGroupName="additionalInfo">
    <input
  type="text"
  pInputText
  formControlName="specialization"
  placeholder="Specialization"
/>
  </ng-container>

Forked Working Example
